# Removing debug logs with ProGuard

Tags: java, logging, proguard

In application we're working on, there's so much debug and trace logging that even when the logging level turns them off, the sole overhead of creating arrays of message arguments becomes an issue in some of our time-sensitive algorithms. Now, we don't want to remove the logs completely (as they are obviously useful during development and on testing environments), but we do want to reduce they runtime overhead somehow. We considered a few options:

- Ditching Slf4j API and using Log4j2 with lazy logging requires too much refactoring and manual labor. Same goes for custom logger wrapper and wrapping all logger invocation with if statements..
- Code post-processor could automatically wrap all logs with conditional statements (so argument arrays are never created) or remove them altogether.
- ProGuard could remove all logger calls.

Since we haven't found any code post-processors that would strip logging out of the box, we decided to go with the ProGuard solution. This is our basic ProGuard setup:

```
-optimizations code/removal/simple,code/removal/advanced
-dontobfuscate
-dontshrink
-keep class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
  *;
}
-assumenosideeffects class org.slf4j.Logger {
  void trace(...);
  void debug(...);
}
```

The solution works partially. Most debug logs are indeed removed, but all methods invoked on debug log arguments are unaffected. For example, this line:

```
log.debug("Evidence {} is unverifiable for product {}", evidence, product.getData().getName());
```

...would be transformed into this:

```
product.getData().getName()
```

Ironically, it also leaves all the object array initiations:

```
log.debug("{} {} {}", first, second, third);
// ...becomes:
Object[] var10000 = new Object[]{first, second, third};
```

Now, I know this sort of thing should be optimized by JIT (unused variables removal) - I'm more worried about the first case, where all invoked methods are not removed along with the logging. These might range from harmless (simple getter invocation) to somewhat worse (`size()` call on a concurrent collection).

The current ProGuard solution is "good enough", but I wonder if it would be possible to remove the logging invocations (and their side effects) completely. Can we achieve this through ProGuard configuration or is there an existing tool designed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just a crazy idea: what about creating your own interface & implementation with identical interfaces to slf4j but with unrolled varargs?  Essentially you fork slf4j to fit your requirements.

Another idea is to build a SLF4J-to-Log4j2 migration tool. If your company agrees you could propose this as a contribution to the Log4j2 project so you don't have to maintain it. :-)

Comment: Custom logging interface is exactly the kind of thing we're trying to avoid -  this would probably require too much manual refactoring work. Switching to Log4j2 API would solve some of our problems though - I'll look into it.

Comment: Fortunately the slf4j API is small; I imagine it's mostly imports, and in code replacing LoggerFactory with LogManager, and MDC by ThreadContext.

Comment: Yeah, it should be just a matter of using find-replace and maybe refactoring some potentially costly logs to use `Suppliers`. Since ProGuard solution already works (kinda, sorta), pairing these two should be sufficient. I hope.